# Javascript RegEx Match Word after character

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have been looking for hours trying to figure this one out, perhaps I can sleep on it. Im trying to RegEx part of a string and replace it with a value depending on the word after a character.

"content.size | price: $content.price"
What I am trying to do is use a RegEx to replace parts of my string with a value. 
I would like to target the entire expression content.size and content.price. But the word after "content." can be anything. I have tried to write an expression but not having any luck

```
var firstString = "content.size | price: $content.price"
var Re = new RegExp(/content.\b/);
var newValue = firstString.match(Re);
console.log(newValue);
```

enter code hereWhat I am expecting from the console is:

```
content.size content.price
```

So then I can say:

```
firstString.replace(newValue, someOtherValue)
```

Comment: input "firstString". output "newValue"
where is the confusion coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your regex is that you are not escaping the decimal point (.) which matches any single character except the newline - documentation is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I have tried the below which returns an array of content.size and content.price

You can try it out and see if it helps you:

```
var firstString = "content.size | price: $content.price";
var regex = /content\.[\S]+/g;
var newValue = firstString.match(regex);
console.log(newValue);
```

Let me know if it helps you.

SO1

Comment: Perfect. I wish I had more resources to learn RegEx for javascript. I don't how I would have ever came to this conclusion that you for the link!

Comment: If the suggestions help then accept one answer because that is why people hang around here to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a replacer function, although I'm not 100% sure I got the question right

```
var firstString = "content.size | price: $content.price"
var regex = new RegExp(/content\.([^ ]*)/g);
var newValue = firstString.replace(regex,function(match, group1){
    if(group1 === 'size'){
        // do something with size here
        return '12';
    }
    // return key if not handled
    return group1;
});
console.log(newValue);
```

**Update:**

As it seems that the question was how to dynamically update size and price here is one more complete example.

```
var data = {size : "12", price : "$ 15.99"};
var firstString = "$content.size | price: $content.price"
var regex = new RegExp(/\$content\.([^ ]*)/g);
var newValue = firstString.replace(regex,function(match, group1){
    if(group1 in data){
        return data[group1];
    }
    // return key if no data present
    return group1;
});
console.log(newValue);
```

I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Interesting, that could actually work. 'if' statement would not be strict though because ==='size' could be anything. but I have a solution for that already. But this function is exactly what I was thinking of! THANKS!
You got the question right!!!!

Comment: That's the part that did not really become clear, obviously you can use group1 to i.e. access properties of an object dynamically or the like.

Comment: yeah so it would be:
` 
if(group1 ===[prop]){
        return [dynamicstuff];
    }
`

Comment: But then again this function does not return both parts of the string if its dynamic, it will only return the last part. so if I do a replace and prop is an object key that holds content.size and content.price  if(group1 ===prop){ return obj[prop]; } then it will only return the price.

Comment: if(group1 ===prop){ return obj[prop]; }else{
return obj[group1]
}
would return every case